# Why does std::localtime give varying offset from UTC?

Tags: c++, date, timezone

I am in the UK, so my timezone is currently the same as UTC. In the following code, if I pass different timestamps to localtime, I get different offsets from UTC (via gmtime). Why is this? My timezone isn't changing from call to call, so I didn't expect the offset to be affected by the timestamp given.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (time_t t = 0; t < 300000000; t+=10000000)
    {
        std::tm *timeInfo;

        // Get UTC time
        timeInfo = std::gmtime(&t);
        auto gm_hours = timeInfo->tm_hour;

        // Get localtime
        timeInfo = std::localtime(&t);

        // Print offset from UTC
        std::cout << "Timestamp: " << t << " Hours ahead of UTC : " << (timeInfo->tm_hour - gm_hours) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Timestamp: 0 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 10000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 20000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 30000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 40000000 Hours ahead of UTC : -23
Timestamp: 50000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 60000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 0
Timestamp: 70000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 80000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 90000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 0
Timestamp: 100000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 0
Timestamp: 110000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 120000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 130000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 0
Timestamp: 140000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 150000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 160000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 0
Timestamp: 170000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 180000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 190000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 0
Timestamp: 200000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 210000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 220000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 0
Timestamp: 230000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 240000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 250000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 0
Timestamp: 260000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 270000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 1
Timestamp: 280000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 0
Timestamp: 290000000 Hours ahead of UTC : 0
```

Comment: Do you aware of the summer and winter time, possible time zone changes in the past?

Comment: I think the [Tom Scott video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) is highly appropriate here.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I didn't see why that should change the representation from localtime. My timezone (or DST) isn't changing during the course of the execution of the program.

Comment: @WillPlatts: But you're asking about the UTC offset in the UK time zone *at different points in time*. The UTC offset *when you're running the code* is irrelevant.

Comment: @Casey I will have a look!

Comment: @JonSkeet - yes thanks, it seems localtime is doing more than I expected! I thought it would just offset UTC by the current localtime offset. I didn't realise it gave the representation at the time of the timestamp. I was also thrown by the fact that timestamp 0 was +1 - as it happens DST worked differently in 1970 than I expected! https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london?year=1970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UK observes daylight savings time, switching to British Summer Time in the summer. Hence, if you pass in a timestamp that falls within the part of the year when British Summer Time is in effect, you will see that your local time is one hour ahead of UTC.